# Error in PHP making it do else

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to get this code to do else if there are no more rows to display but not working could anyone point me in the right direction for fixing this.

```
if($mymethod == "LOADGEMINVENTORY")
{

 $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM gemshop_table LIMIT $startrow, 6")or
die(mysql_error());//Pulles six items at a time to display.

if(!mysql_error()){ echo ("DISPLAYING6OFINVENTORY^");         
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
     { 
       echo $row['id'];echo (",");echo $row['image'];echo ("^"); 
     }
     }else{echo ("NOINVENTORY");}

}
```

Comment: Doesn't work how? Is it failing with an error?

Comment: sorry it pulls the info and works right but when there is no more data it keeps returning blank i need it to display a message if there are no more rows

Comment: You are expecting an error to be the signal that there are no rows to read?

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing `mysqli` with `mysql`. You should really use one of these in your code.

If you're using mysqli, you can do the following to get number of rows:

```
$row_count = $result->num_rows;

if( $row_count == 0 ) {
echo "NOINVENTORY";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

These is no while/else condition in PHP (or most programming language that I know of).

[while()](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.while.php) will automatically loop through the data until the end. So in your case, if you want to show something *after* all the data has been retrieved, you would just show it after the while() loop.

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{ 
   echo $row['id'];echo (",");echo $row['image'];echo ("^"); 
}

echo "Show anything you want after the data above.";
```

However, it seems to me that you want to show the records when you have data, and NOINVENTORY when there's none. For that, use [if()](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php) statement with [num_rows](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php)

```php
if(!mysql_error())
{
     if (0 == mysqli_num_rows ($result))
     {
        echo "NOINVENTORY";
     }
     else
     {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        { 
           echo $row['id'];echo (",");echo $row['image'];echo ("^"); 
        }
     }
}
```